# CSS animted gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Hello I am trying to make smoother changing angle (deg) of gradient in CSS. I wanna to make it animated like rolling.

Video showcase:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xFHR.jpg

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  margin:0;
  
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, #007fff 55%, #f5fafa 45%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background: linear-gradient(340deg, #f5fafa 60%, #007fff 40%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with gradient but you can use rotation like below:

```css
html::before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 150vmax;
  width: 150vmax;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #007fff 55%, #f5fafa 45%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(115deg);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  html::before {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(155deg);
  }
}
```